# performing a summation operation in matlab under some conditions

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following matrix, named interact:

```
interact = [1 2;
            1 3; 
            2 1;
            2 3;
            3 1;
            3 4; 
            4 1]
```

This matrix means that 1 and 2 interact, 1 and 3 interact, and so on. (just a matrix full of indices.)

Now I want to perform this operation/task.

All that 1 interacts will be added and stored in a matrix. Meaning the interaction between 1 and 2 + interaction between 1 and 3 = interaction of 1.

Separate matrices for interaction of 2, 3, 4.

How do I do this in matlab?

Comment: It would help if you wrote out (in a proper MATLAB variable format) the full output you are looking for for your sample data

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I understand your question. You have an array with values, called `values`. You also have an array with interactions, called `interact`. You now want to construct a third array, `result`, where the first element is the interactions of 1, the second element is the interactions of 2 etc. `interact` has in the first column the index of the element ("which element is interacting?"), and in the second column the indices of the elements the one in the first column interacts with ("who are the interaction partners?").

```
%# make up some values
values = rand(1,4);

%# use your interactions
interact = [1 2;
            1 3; 
            2 1;
            2 3;
            3 1;
            3 4; 
            4 1]

%# calculate
result = accumarray(interact(:,1),values(interact(:,2)), [], @sum, NaN);
```